# Python Lib to excute remote windows commands from a linux Box without using ssh

Tags: linux, python-2.7, remote-access

This a very basic requirement of our project.

I need to run Windows command from a linux box, without using ssh, as not all the windows boxes have ssh installed by default.

I was searching for some python libs that can do this work?

Links, tutorial, are highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: run a process inside a windows host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164351/python-run-a-process-inside-a-windows-host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some alternatives:

- http://www.krenger.ch/blog/wmi-commands-from-linux/
- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/ (under wine or a Windows bridge VM)
- https://code.google.com/p/impacket/source/browse/trunk/examples/psexec.py